# Find out what stored procedure modified a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to monitor a table for some time and find out which stored procedure modified it?

I figure you can use this to see all refrences...'

```
USE PDEV

SELECT 
    referencing_object_name = obj.name, 
    referencing_object_type_desc = obj.type_desc, 
    referenced_object_name = referenced_entity_name
FROM 
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sd 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects obj ON sd.referencing_id = obj.[object_id] 
WHERE 
    referenced_entity_name = 'ORDER_DETAIL'
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Short answer: No, with a but...

Comment: sql-server.  (SQL sever management studio)

Comment: A more targeted query to find candidate stored procs (that don't just reference it for reading) is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729903/73226

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do, but you need to setup **SQL Server Auditing**.

Read more in the Microsoft documentation. For example, start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I only have the standard edition. So I can't use that feature for the database... I was looking into Express Profiler and seeing if I can use a trace to find out what calls the stored procedure...